# Change position on Ctags Taglist in Vim

Tags: vim, ctags, taglist

I'm using the wonderful [Taglist plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) with Vim and I would like to know if there is any way to change the position of the list.
I'd like to make it popup from the right part of the screen instead of the left, where it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Taglist doc:

```
                                                *'Tlist_Use_Right_Window'*
Tlist_Use_Right_Window
By default, the vertically split taglist window will appear on the left hand
side. If you prefer to open the window on the right hand side, you can set the
'Tlist_Use_Right_Window' variable to 1:

        let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1
```

Link to the [taglist-options](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/manual.html#taglist-options) section.

Comment: Thanks, I browsed the documentation and I can't believed I missed that.

Comment: That's the importance of knowing and using the right nomenclature. I'm saying that just because I noticed the word "Window" was missing in your question. Please, don't get it the wrong way. ;)